# Parse JSON File with PHP

Tags: php, html, json

I had a problem when parse my json data with php in select html element

This my [JSON DATA](http://en.textsave.org/WjQ)

This my [PHP CODE](http://txs.io/Yfqb)

Error message :

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 6
```

This line 6 :

```
$provider = $jfo->product->provider;
```

I try to parse "provider" to select html element after someone choose "Jenis Produk".

Comment: You should add the relevant code directly to your question instead of linking to it. It will keep the question coherent when the link goes dead at any point in the future.

Answer (score 0):

product is not an object, it is an array:

```
$jfo->product['provider'];
```

Comment: More error : Notice: Undefined index: provider in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 6

Comment: Like @Bilyukov said, it's an array, but an indexed one, so you need to do something like `$jfo->product[0]->provider` and so on. You might want to do a `foreach` through `$jfo->product` to get all providers from all products.

Answer (score 0):

product is an array, containing multiple products.

```
$jfo->product[0]->provider;
```

You'll need to loop through the products.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($jfo->product); $i++) {
  $provider = $jfo->product[$i]->provider;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It appears that `product` is not an object.

Have you tried dumping $jfo->product?

My guess is that it is an array.